# Alter rewrite rules to end with trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

so I have the following url rewriting rules;

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ (.*)/index.php[^\ ]*\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^f([0-9]+)-[^_]+?\.html$ viewforum.php?f=$1
RewriteRule ^f([0-9]+)-[^_]+?_([0-9]+)\.html$ viewforum.php?f=$1&start=$2
RewriteRule ^t([0-9]+)-[^_]+?\.html$ viewtopic.php?t=$1
RewriteRule ^egosearch.html$ search.php?search_id=egosearch
```

They change a query string into a string with a trailing `.html`.  Could someone help me switch these over so they only show a trailing slash?

The current URLS look like this :

```
/f2-general-auto-assistance.html
/t1-welcome-to-phpbb3.html
/faq.html
```

Additionally, I would like to learn more about using rewrite rules. So if you would please share a reference url for learning more so I can do this myself in the future - that would be excellent.

Comment: Is this rule `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %2/ [R=301,L]` working?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be working great as it is.  Why, is it written incorrectly?

Comment: `%2` will always be empty here.

Comment: I had the order pasted wrong, I corrected it.

Comment: hey @anubhava - I updated my example, and also shared what the current URLs are formatted to look like.  Do you know how to change them to trailing slashes?

Comment: So instead of `/faq.html` you want `/faq.html/` to show in browser?

Comment: No, rather than /faq.html I would prefer /faq/

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this by making last `.html` part optional and allowing a trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ (.*)/index.php[^\ ]*\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^f([0-9]+)-[^_]+?(/|\.html)$ viewforum.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^f([0-9]+)-[^_]+?_([0-9]+)(/|\.html)$ viewforum.php?f=$1&start=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^t([0-9]+)-[^_]+?(/|\.html)$ viewtopic.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^egosearch(/|\.html)$ search.php?search_id=egosearch [L,QSA]
```